# Javascript current time function to work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my custom video controls to show the current time of the video.  However I can not get it to function.  What am I missing in my code?

Javascript Code

```
var time = document.getElementById("current");

time.addEventListener("timeupdate", currentTime, true);

// Current time function 

function currentTime() {

    var currentMinutes = Math.floor(video.currentTime / 60);
    var currentSeconds = Math.floor(video.currentTime - currentMinutes * 60);


    time.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;     
}
```

HTML5

```
<div id="time">
    <span id="current">00:00</span> 
    <span id="duration">00:00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is it that you expect to fire a "timeupdate" event on that `<span>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an event trigger off the event. Since you're using a video, I would use the video `ontimeupdate` event.

There appears to be something wrong with the time displaying. But I got the video event stuff working here in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/83peL34r/

Javascript:

```
var time = document.getElementById("current");
var video = document.getElementById("video");

time.addEventListener("timeupdate", currentTime, true);
video.ontimeupdate = function() {currentTime()};

// Current time function 

function currentTime() {

    var currentMinutes = Math.floor(video.currentTime / 60);
    var currentSeconds = Math.floor(video.currentTime - currentMinutes * 60);


  time.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;

}
```

HTML:

```
<video id="video" width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="time">
  <span id="current">00:00</span> 
  <span id="duration">00:00</span>
</div>
```

Edit: I've made some changes to get you a little further. In this one, it grabs the duration and puts it in the duration section. And if the seconds is less than 10 it pads it with a 0 in front of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/83peL34r/1/

Comment: Thank you Joshua Terrill.  That was really helpful.  I will make sure I remember that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have something like this:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
</video>

<div id="time">
  <span id="current">00:00</span> 
  <span id="duration">00:00</span>
</div>
```

Do this:

```
var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
var currentTime = document.getElementById('current');
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  var currentMinutes = Math.floor(video.currentTime / 60);
  var currentSeconds = Math.floor(video.currentTime - currentMinutes * 60);

  currentTime.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;
});
```

In you code, you added a timeupdate event listener to your span. You should add it to the video element.